# How to make blueimp gallery textFactory work with an iframe

Tags: blueimp

I have followed the documentation here:

https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery

First loaded assets separatedly.

Then created `blueimp-gallery-textFactory.js` and loaded after core file, before video file, with the following contents:

```
blueimp.Gallery.prototype.textFactory = function (obj, callback) {
    var $element = $('<div>')
            .addClass('text-content')
            .attr('title', obj.title);

    var iframe=$('<iframe>', {
      src: obj.href,
      frameborder: 0,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      scrolling: 'no'
    });

    $element.html(iframe);

    callback({
      type: 'load',
      target: $element[0]
    });

    return $element[0];
};
```

So what changes from original example is that I'm not making an ajax request and then running callback, but instead creating an iframe and then running callback.

And also added the aditional css style to the stylesheet:

```
.blueimp-gallery > .slides > .slide > .text-content {
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 60px auto;
    padding: 0 60px;
    max-width: 920px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

The issue I ran into is that the onLoad/complete event would never fire and the slideLoading class will be always on top of the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I started to look into the videoFactory plugin and youtube one to see what could be wrong.

So I've stole some CSS from the video plugin:

```
.blueimp-gallery > .slides > .slide > .text-content > iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}
.blueimp-gallery > .slides > .slide > .text-content > iframe {
  top: 0;
}
```

This (helps) but did not solve the problem.

What did solve the problem was taken from `blueimp-gallery-video.js` and that is running the callback with this `setTimeout` function.

```
blueimp.Gallery.prototype.textFactory = function (obj, callback) {
    var $element = $('<div>')
            .addClass('text-content')
            .attr('title', obj.title);

    var iframe=$('<iframe>', {
      src: obj.href,
      frameborder: 0,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      scrolling: 'no'
    });

    $element.html(iframe);

//    callback({
//      type: 'load',
//      target: $element[0]
//    });

    this.setTimeout(callback, [
      {
        type: 'load',
        target: $element[0]
      }
    ]);

    return $element[0];
};
```

This time the problem got solved. I guess with the $.get ajax call from original example there was no need to call `setTimeout` but with the iframe it was required.